# Running a mapping task what is the correct 2nd array method for processing one of the newly created item's values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, mapping, lookup

I have an array containing objects:

```
let sportTag = [
    { id: 1, name: 'FOOTBALL', found: false },
    { id: 2, name: 'TENNIS'  , found: false },
    { id: 3, name: 'BASKET'  , found: false },
]
```

I have also have another array containing objects and for every object a field (`sports`) that is an array:

```
let person = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Mark", 
    age: 23,
    sports: ["volleyball", "rugby", "tennis"],
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: "Rupert",
    age: 40,
    sports: ["golf"],
}, {
    id: 3,
    name: "John",
    age: 31,
    sports: ["football", "golf", "rugby", "tennis"],
}]
```

I would like to change sportTag found field to true when sportTag name is equal to every person sport.
I tried with a nested map

```
const result = sportTag.map(st => {
    person.map(p => {
        p.sports.map(s => {
            if (st.name.toLocaleUpperCase() === s.toLocaleUpperCase()) {
                return {
                    ...st, found: true
                }
            }
            return s
        })
        return p
    })
    return st
})

console.log(sportTag)
//OUTPUT
// { id: 1, name: 'FOOTBALL', found: false },
// { id: 2, name: 'TENNIS'  , found: false },
// { id: 3, name: 'BASKET'  , found: false }
console.log(result)
//OUTPUT
// { id: 1, name: 'FOOTBALL', found: false },
// { id: 2, name: 'TENNIS'  , found: false },
// { id: 3, name: 'BASKET'  , found: false }
```

Why are the changes not reflected in the `result`? I expect the output to be:

```
{ id: 1, name: 'FOOTBALL', found: true  },
{ id: 2, name: 'TENNIS'  , found: true  },
{ id: 3, name: 'BASKET'  , found: false }
```

Comment: You always return `st`, which is never modified anywhere.

Comment: The OP already mentions in the description of the problem the correct way of achieving what the OP wants ... _"I would like to change [the] `sportTag`'s `found` field to `true` when [the] `sportTag`'s `name` [value] is equal to ---every--- [\[`some`\]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) `person`'s `sport` [item]."_ ... thus the OP does not need to implement a nested, twice `map` but a `map`/`some` task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are always returning `st` for each iteration of the first `map`, so you get the original values.

You probably want something like this:

```js
const result = sportTag.map(st => {
    const foundSport = person.find(p => 
        p.sports.find(s => st.name.toLocaleUpperCase() === s.toLocaleUpperCase())
    );
    return foundSport
        ? { ...st, found: true }
        : st;
});

console.log(sportTag)
// { id: 1, name: 'FOOTBALL', found: false },
// { id: 2, name: 'TENNIS', found: false },
// { id: 3, name: 'BASKET', found: false }
console.log(result)
// { id: 1, name: 'FOOTBALL', found: true },
// { id: 2, name: 'TENNIS', found: true },
// { id: 3, name: 'BASKET', found: false }
```

Answer (score 1):

From the above comment ...

> The OP already mentions in the description of the problem the correct way of achieving what the OP wants ... *"I would like to change [the] `sportTag`'s `found` field to `true` when [the] `sportTag`'s `name` [value] is equal to <strike>every</strike> [`any`/[`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)] `person`'s `sport` [item]."* ... thus the OP does not need to implement a nested, twice `map` but a `map`/`some` task.

But (especially for a bigger amount of data) instead of following the above suggested approach which within every `map` iteration additionally iterates again with every nested `some` task, one could choose a lookup based approach which works with a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instance. The mapping task itself will be very simple. For the latter one could even choose an implementation which makes the mapping agnostic to the current lookup's variable/constant name since one would provide its reference as [the `map` method's 2nd `thisArg` parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#parameters_in_detail).

One of cause could implement the lookup creation with less iteration cycles. But since it is done once it will never become the performance bottleneck.

```js
function createLookupOfAnyPracticedSport(persons) {
  return new Map(
    // (5) create a map as lookup for unique sport items.
    Array
      // (3) create array from set of step (2)
      .from(
        new Set(
          // (2) create a set of unique sport
          //     items/values as of step (1)
          persons
            // (1) concatenate array of all `sports`
            //     practiced by any person.
            .reduce((result, { sports }) =>
              result.concat(sports), []
            )
        )
      )
      // (4) sanitize and map the unique  sport items/values
      //     in order to qualify as entries for step (5) ...
      .map(sport => [sport.toLocaleUpperCase(), true])
  );
}
function createUpToDateSportTagFromBoundSports(tagItem) {
  const allSportsLookup = this;

  // create (updated) shallow copy of the original
  // sport tag item in order to not directly mutate
  // such an item's original reference.
  return {
    ...tagItem,
    found: allSportsLookup
      .has(tagItem.name.toLocaleUpperCase())
  };
}

const personList = [{
  id: 1, name: "Mark", age: 23,
  sports: ["volleyball", "rugby", "tennis"],
}, {
  id: 2, name: "Rupert", age: 40,
  sports: ["golf"],
}, {
  id: 3, name: "John", age: 31,
  sports: ["football", "golf", "rugby", "tennis"],
}];

const sportTagList = [{
  id: 1, name: 'FOOTBALL', found: false,
}, {
  id: 2, name: 'TENNIS', found: false,
}, {
  id: 3, name: 'BASKET', found: false,
}];

const mappedTagList = sportTagList
  .map(
    createUpToDateSportTagFromBoundSports,
    createLookupOfAnyPracticedSport(personList),    
  );

console.log({
  mappedTagList,
  sportTagList,
  personList,
});
console.log(
  'entries of any practiced sport ...',
  [...createLookupOfAnyPracticedSport(personList).entries()],
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let person = [{
  id: 1, name: "Mark", age: 23,
  sports: ["volleyball", "rugby", "tennis"],
}, {
  id: 2, name: "Rupert", age: 40,
  sports: ["golf"],
}, {
  id: 3, name: "John", age: 31,
  sports: ["football", "golf", "rugby", "tennis"],
}];

let sportTag = [{
  id: 1, name: 'FOOTBALL', found: false,
}, {
  id: 2, name: 'TENNIS', found: false,
}, {
  id: 3, name: 'BASKET', found: false,
}]; 

sportTag.forEach((elem, index, array) => {
  person.forEach((el, i, arr) => {
    if (person[i].sports.indexOf(sportTag[index].name.toLocaleLowerCase()) != -1) {
      sportTag[index].found = true;
    }
  });
});
console.log(sportTag);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Besides the mutation of the original `sportTag` items (which was not the OP's intention) the above implementation of the inner `forEach`/`indexOf` combination is far from ideal since the inner `forEach` will always fully iterate (it would not matter whether an `sports` item was found right in the beginning or in the very end). Thus an already improved implementation was based on an outer `forEach` and an inner `some` or even an outer `map` (including the OP's spread syntax) and the inner `some`.